# How to successfully inherit ActiveRecord::Base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord, devise

How to successfully inherit ActiveRecord::Base?

Environment: Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1, PostreSQL 9.3.3, Devise 3.2.4

I have an operational app and would like to add a comprehensive logging class to it.  This will be a complex class that not only logs messages but also creates an SQL database that logs transactions by object.  I need this class available throughout all of the classes in the application.

To do this, I wanted to inherit ActiveRecord::Base into the class and then have all other classes inherit it, though I don't plan to use STI.  That seemed to be a lot simpler in concept than in practice, even though I thought such inheritance was a common best practice.  Am I missing something?

One of the initial tables was this:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```

I set it up like this:

```
class XLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  def initialize
  end
end
class Device < XLog
...
end
```

Prior to this change, the app was working fine.  After this change, when I login I receive:

```
ArgumentError at /devices/sign_in
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

The error occurs in:

```
bin/rails, line 4
```

bin/rails is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

Device is the Devise "User" class in this application and the error occurs when I try to login.  If I change Device to inherit ActiveRecord::Base, it lets me login and run.

But, then I get another error whenever I call "new" on the other classes:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I am definitely missing something when it comes to this inheritance.  Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialize method was throwing the error.  It was triggering every time a subclass was initialized and was configured to accept 0 parameters.  When I removed it, the whole thing started working.  If I need it, I'll have to configure it to accept a variable number of parameters and pass them as expected, I guess.